# Google maps styling query

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've played around with the FusionTablesLayer Wizard (http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/fusiontableslayer_builder.html) to create a map of wind turbines in North Devon.

http://www.thisisnorthdevon.co.uk/images/localpeople/ugc-images/275834/binaries/WindTurbines.html

But there are two problems.

The first is that the styling that I'd created within the Fusion Table layers has not carried through. Is there a switch to force the layer to take on this styling?

The second is that I don't want the shapefile layer to be clickable. How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But there are two problems.
>
> - The first is that the styling that I'd created within the Fusion Table layers has not
>   carried through. Is there a switch to force the layer to take on this styling?

Not sure what styling you are asking about.  Is it styling defined in the FusionTable?  By the FusionTables Wizard? It looks like you may be missing the application of the styles to the map this or the equivalent:

```
 map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```

You might want to review the [documentation on styling the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype)

> - The second is that I don't want the shapefile layer to be clickable. How do I turn this off?

To disable clicks on that FusionTablesLayer, use the [suppressInfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions) option when you construct it.

[your page with infowindows suppressed on the polygon layer and styling](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_thisisnorthdevon_co_uk_WindTurbines.html), note that your html is invalid (no body).

Comment: First query: It's possible to style up the info window from within Fusion Tables, but when I use the wizard, it does not pick up the styling I applied. Thanks for your help with the second query. Much appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The styled contents of the infoWindow should be available in the layer click event; if you are creating your own infoWindows (or if the styling wizard is), then you need to write code to style the infoWindow however you like.

Comment: It was. I'm a twerp. I've created several versions of the same map and hadn't updated the styling on each version. I'm slowly learning the programmer mindset, but not quickly. Forgive my ignorance. My only excuse is I'm a journalist first, hacker second. I'm currently trying to learn terminal on Mac after 15 years on PC. It's not difficult, but takes a mindset to learn that I've not had for many years.